iSCSI LUN Unrecognized During High Usage by Proxmox Guest VMs
I'm experiencing an issue with my Proxmox setup where the iSCSI LUN becomes unrecognized during high usage by guest VMs. The VMs have their disks backed by this iSCSI LUN. Initially, everything works fine, but after a while, the drives stop working.
Setup:

Proxmox VE Version: 8.2.2
TrueNAS Version: TrueNAS-SCALE-24.04.0
iSCSI Target: TrueNAS
LUN Size: 1TB

Commands and Outputs:

iSCSI Session Verification:
iscsiadm -m session -P 1

Target: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:proxmox-truenas-iscsi-1tb (non-flash)
        Current Portal: 192.168.10.14:3260,1
        Persistent Portal: 192.168.10.14:3260,1
        iSCSI Connection State: LOGGED IN
        iSCSI Session State: LOGGED_IN


Volume Group Status Check:
vgdisplay proxmox-truenas-lun

Volume group "proxmox-truenas-lun" not found


Physical Volume Check:
pvscan

PV /dev/sda3   VG pve             lvm2 [<930.48 GiB / 16.00 GiB free]


iSCSI Device Listing:
ls /dev/disk/by-path/

ip-192.168.10.14:3260-iscsi-iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:proxmox-truenas-iscsi-1tb-lun-0


Manual iSCSI Login Attempt:
iscsiadm -m node --targetname iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:proxmox-truenas-iscsi-1tb --portal 192.168.10.14 --login

iscsiadm: default: 1 session requested, but 1 already present.
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals


Block Device Listing:
lsblk

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdj         8:144  0  1000G  0 disk 
├─proxmox--truenas--lun-vm--101--disk--0
└─proxmox--truenas--lun-vm--101--disk--1


LVM Physical Volume Display:
pvdisplay /dev/sdj

Cannot use /dev/sdj: device is too small (pv_min_size)


System Logs:
journalctl -xe

I/O error, dev sdj, sector [various sectors] op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x208800



Any insights on why the iSCSI LUN becomes unrecognized and how to prevent this from happening would be greatly appreciated.
